# Intellij Structural Search non final

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

Using the `Copy existing template...` I found the structural search for loops:

```
for ($Type$ $Variable$ : $Expression$) {
  $Statement$;
}
```

I want to enhance it so that it does only find for loops where the variable is not final.

It should find:

```
for (String string : strings) {
    // Statements
}
```

However not:

```
for (final String string : strings) {
    // Statements
}
```

Right now it obviously finds both since there's no differentiation between final and non-final. How can I add this extra check?

Comment: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5262495 suggests that there is an undocumented feature: `!__context__.hasModifierProperty("final")`.

Comment: Does not seem to work if I prepend that to the search. Also if I only search for `!__context__.hasModifierProperty("final")` I can't find any match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Start with the existing template *foreach loops*.
- Click *Edit Variables...* and select the *Variable* variable.
- In the *Script Constraints* text field enter `!__context__.hasModifierProperty("final")`.

Click OK and Find and you should get your desired result.
See also the existing template *static fields that are not final* for an example.